# How Can I get Correct User Public IP Address in Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ip-address

## Problem

How can I get Visitor's Public IP Address in Flask? I have tried `request.remote_addr` but It returns Visitor's Private IP starting with `10.1.xx.xxx` where my Public IP is `103.26.247.xxx`. This IP Randomly Changed after refreshing. I have tried online ip lookup tool with `10.1.16.96` this ip which I got from `remote_addr`. It says this is a private ip. Then I tried with `requests` module. I have send a get request to `https://api.ipify.org`. It returns Visitor's Correct Public IP. But It only works when I run it on localhost. However, I hosted that test project to heroku. You can find that [here](https://ip-checker-flask.herokuapp.com/). But then, the ip which I got from `requests.get` method, It doesn't change on different ip. I think the reason of it the get request sent from the server. That's why it's showing server ip. But How Can I find correct User Public IP in flask??

## Code

Here is the simple project
(I know about `render_template` but It's a little test project bro. I wanna learn)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    remote_ip=request.remote_addr
    success=False
    while not success:
        try:
            get_ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
            success=True
        except ConnectionError:
            continue
        except ConnectTimeout:
            continue
    return f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Check Your IP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>This is Found by "request.remote_addr" : { remote_ip }</h2>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>And this is found by "requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text" method : { get_ip }</h2>
        <h3>This one actually the servers ip. Cz the get method sent by the server with "requests" module</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>"""


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to take a possible proxy into account, I would also query the [XFF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header. See also the [RFC 7239](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7239) specification. Depending on the proxy, however, different HTTP headers are possible.

```
remote_ip = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For', request.remote_addr)
```